# How to input a location in android

Tags: android

I have an application where the user has to choose a location on the map. I was wondering whats the right Intent to call for this purpose for a graphical interface with google maps. Is there any standard way to do this? 
Secondly if the user only wants to enter the location of a place using a text box is there any way to show hints of the place depending on the location of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an external library avaible for android for using google map mapview -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

for searching for some places you can use the google places API (https://developers.google.com/places/) to handle it
you can create a textbox and get the input from it and search it for an example if you want to search some 'food' in the sydney australia you can use this

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

it'll return you a json data after that you can parse it to get the latitude and longitude of the places and view it in the mapview

or you can also use google map JavaScript API, I think the function is almost same but you create it in the HTML file and show it in the android webview and if you using this you can also use it in the iOS application with showing the HTML file in the UIWebView

if there's any question you can ask me via comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am not sure about Textbox, But if you only want to take input from map you can ask user to tap on map which puts marker on map location.which can be done by **OnTap** method.here is the link of How to do it [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android-example/) and [here](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-map-view-double-taps-and-overlay-markers/)